# Is there a way in which I can make different dataflow jobs for each kafka message without having to wait until one finishes to start the next one?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, dataflow

I have a trigger on google cloud storage that fires when a new file is uploaded, it sends some info of the file to a kafka topic, I want the consumer to receive the message and create a job for that message on cloud dataflow but I dont want to wait until the job finishes to consume another message from kafka because I need multiple jobs running at the same time.

[consumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AjSr.png)

[pipelineFunctionInsideConsumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLVjN.png)

Comment: Can you show the consumer code? Why is it currently blocking if you don't want it to? In other words, have you tried doing the processing logic in a separate thread from the consumer?

Comment: I updated the post with the photos, I think the problem is that the consumer is not going to keep going until the pipe function(which is inside the consumer) ends, but I have no idea how to procced or where should I begin  to make this idea work...also about executing the logic separatedly from the consumer I honestly dont have any idea on how to do that, can you tell me please which topic/documentation should I read for that?

Comment: 1) Please share code as text, not images 2) Beam/Dataflow already has a Kafka pipeline input function. You shouldn't really be using the Confluent library at all, but yeah, downloading GCS files should ideally be blocking call, but that doesn't stop you from having multiple topic partitions and running multiple consumers/pipelines

Comment: ok thank you for your quick answers

Comment: I have an idea on how to proceed now,one last question... where should I run the consumer/beam/dataflow code If I want it to be constantly checking the kafka messages is there a cloud service for that? or  iDataflow itself is going to be checking kafka constantlly?

Comment: Reading from Kafka is a streaming job. [From docs](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-production-ready-data-pipelines-using-dataflow-deploying#life_of_a_dataflow_job) - "Streaming jobs that enter a JOB_STATE_RUNNING state can continue running indefinitely until they're cancelled or drained, unless a job failure occurs"